# Is it possible to use gerund after "during"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

> *During reading the book, I fell asleep*.

I think "while" is more suitable but I want to know if it is grammatically correct to use "during" here. If it is possible, is there any difference?

Comment: _During cleaning_ or _while they were being cleaned_.

Comment: I agree, for those two examples. But for this example, "While cleaning the pantry, I got my clothes dirty.", it seems to me that it must be "while".

Comment: @KateBunting Can we not say _While cleaning, my clothes got dirty._? Like "while" with the present progressive tense?

Comment: I had interpreted the sentence in a different way (which doesn't make a lot of sense). If it means 'cleaning the house',  @DhanishthaGhosh 's version is a dangling modifier. _While I was cleaning [the house], my clothes got dirty_ - or Jack's version.

Comment: @KateBunting So is it okay to use it or is it grammatically incorrect?

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh If you omit the _I was_, the literal meaning of your sentence is that the clothes were doing the cleaning. https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-dangling-modifier-1690415

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a gerund, it's the present participle. For the present participle, you should use "while". For it to be a gerund, it needs a determiner:  "During my reading the book, I fell asleep." That's a bit awkward, but grammatically correct.